# Mail Sending problem with Outlook 2010 beta

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010

Thus far my mail was working,i can send and receive message.

But Today When i compose and send a new mail it just goes and sits in my outbox and mail progress window
shows sending.... None of my mails where sent...

Any suggestion....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repair the Microsoft Office 2010 beta installation... this continuously happens to me. After repairing it'll be fixed for a while but will probably come back, and I'm not sure where to go from there.